# multiple containers deployment in azure container group

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I want to deploy multiple containers inside the azure container instances. I checked the limit for Number of containers per container group 60 but the compute and storage limits are as follows:

for example in Japan east max cpu 2 and max memory is 8GB

how can we deploy multiple containers in a container group with such limits on cpu and memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked here and yes, that's right:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability

Have a try how the containers work asynchronously and what the requirements of a container instance are. Describe these inside the docker-compose.yaml under deploy section and try deploying to the group. Note that containers are designed for minimal units or services. You should monitor the performance once deployed - use Azure Monitor to get the exact usage metrics. I believe the deployments will fail if there are not enough resources available for the next containers deployed:

deploy:
resources:
limits:
memory: 4g